# Inconvenientes con funcion para cerrar sesion en C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código en C# para cerrar sesion, pero desafortunadamente no me la cierra pues el botón del navegador le permite al usuario ir al menú y no debe ir sino solo al formulario Iniciar_sesion donde se le pide el usuario y la contraseña:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASP.NETCRUD
{
public partial class CerrarSesion : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Session.Clear();
        //   Response.Redirect("~/inicio_sesion.aspx");
       
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
         HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
         HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();
        Session["usuario"] = null;
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
      //  Response.Cookies.Add(now.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Inicio_sesion.aspx");

    }
  }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Al margen de la redirección, puedes probar con Session.Abandon()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto al redireccionamiento, puedes intentar 2 cosas:

1. A tu invocación del método Redirect, agrégale el segundo parámetro ("EndResponse") con el valor true, de la siguiente manera:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Inicio_sesion.aspx", true);
```

2. Si eso no te funciona, entonces puedes probar establecerlo en false (que es el valor por defecto), y a continuación declarar explícitamente que se complete la solicitud HTTP, de la siguiente manera:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Inicio_sesion.aspx", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

En cuanto a eliminar correctamente la sessión del usuario, puedes probar:

```
Session.Remove("usuario");
```

En vez de:

```
Session["usuario"] = null;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias matias, ya implemente el código pero este es el inconveniente que se me presenta: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXnrCaXzzXU

Comment: @MartínezHernán es imposible evitar que el botón "BACK" / "ATRÁS" en el navegador esté habilitado, habiendo ya navegado al menos 1 página, pues eso no lo puedes controlar desde el código ASP .NET (que funciona y se ejecuta en el servidor).

Comment: @MartínezHernán por otro lado lo que debes hacer es poner un código en el evento Page_Load de todas las páginas (a excepción de "Inicio_sesion.aspx") para que redireccionar hacia la página de login en caso de no estar logueado. De esta manera evitas que puedan cargar cualquier página a la que no tengan acceso.
Algo así:
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( Session["usuario"] == null )
    {
          HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Inicio_sesion.aspx", false);
    }
}

Comment: Muchas gracias Matias, ya arregle el inconveniente de lo de las sesiones de usuario, un cordial saludo .